# hr behind div in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have code working on all desktop brosers, but in mobile it has a bug.

[image]

The lines are hr elements and the square in the middle is a div. The div has position: relative and fixed width and height. I don't use z order.

On mobile all I can do for now is display the background of the div element with certain color, and I can see its indeed occupying the space. I also see in this case, where I use background color, that the hr appears behind it.

Additional information which could be useful: The div in the middle is part of an horizontal ul element, which contains list images with items and also text. Also called content slider ;)

When I initialize the slider with some image slides in it, on mobile, the layout is always displayed correctly. Also when I'm viewing only content slides. But when I put only content slides from the beginning, this error appears.

I don't know what it is... tried getting this behaviour with desktop browser, to find the cause, but didn't success. I don't know why the hr goes there. There's no relation with the content in the slide. The position where the hr appears is somewhere in the middle, between the text...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be most convenient to see your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any of your code, a "best guess" based on past experience is:
It looks like you might have floated content inside of your slider, and the slider itself is not ["cleared"](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

If you have any floated content inside of the slider, make sure the outer slider div is cleared.